# C# Know if server is being accessed from application

Tags: c#, authentication

I have recently created an API on my server in PHP, but I have discovered that I shouldn't use my API directly with an API key because sensitive information like that can't be held securly inside an EXE. I did some research and people recommend creating a proxy between the API and your application, but even still that can be broken into.

I was wondering, how can I make my server know if it is being accessed from my C# application, or from another source? The reason why I want to know is to stop potential hackers accessing my gateway and using it themselves.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you ask clients to authenticate at the gateway? You could require a certificate or something like that. I don't see how someone would easily spoof a certificate from a trusted CA.

Comment: How would I go about that? Is that in terms of Asymmetric authentication?

Comment: Certificate only helps if you trust that the person you give it to won't use it maliciously.  That seems to not be the case here since Joel (rightly) doesn't trust the people he gives his EXE to.

Comment: @Robert Do you have any suggestions on how I could go about protecting my gateway? Any alternate methods to what Esteban has suggested?

Comment: Nope, see John's answer.  You either have to guarantee that nothing bad will happen by random people calling your API or you have to authenticate the end users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL with a login?

There is **no** way for you to be certain someone is using your application to access a web service. I'm in a similar boat, and the most you can do is ensure the communication channel is secure (SSL) and use a username/password or something similar. You also have to be aware that anything done on the client's computer can be compromised. So much so, that you should pretty much assume that your application will be open source to anyone that wants it.

Comment: +1.  I should also add that the idea of proxy webservice doesn't really help.  You could use certs or an IP whitelist to ensure that your API is only being accessed by the proxy server... but that's just shifting the problem.  Now you have to ensure that your *proxy* is only being accessed by your application.  At some point you eventually need to either have user logins or ensure that the API behavior is such that no harm can be done by bad guys calling it.